# Was the Music System for the Exidy Sorcerer as exceptional as I remember?

Tags: sound, exidy-sorcerer

I am trying to remember about a bare-board sound card which plugged into the parallel port of an Exidy Sorcerer (circa 1980). The card and software ("Music System") was made by Arrington Software Service in Boise, Idaho. It had no speaker, so it needed to be plugged into an amplifier and speaker. (Your home music system would work if it had an input jack.) One could enter the 4-voice song from sheet music, or you could buy pre-compiled digital music libraries. Note that the system was polyphonic, but not stereo.

Unfortunately I don't have either my Sorcerer or the sound card anymore.  I'd like to know what D/A converter the latter used.  Maybe I was just ignorant, but I don't remember any other such system, with both 4 voices and the ability to type in sheet music.  The editor literally looked like part of a page of sheet music.

**Did other systems of the era have these features?**

---

... scavenged around and found Mr. Arrington's 1980 brochure in a cabinet. Quoted extract:

> HARDWARE -- Assembled A/D converter connects to parallel port. Simply connect an amplifier to your stereo to listen to music. ...

(sic; I'm sure he meant "D/A")

> MUSIC GENERATION -- Machine language routine generates four part harmony of true frequencies over a 4 and 1/2 octave range.  The routine easily interfaces with your Basic programs to add sound effects and music.  Well documented.
>
> EDITOR -- System includes a screen editor that displays the two musical staves upon which musical notes are placed. ...

It cost $40 (which today would probably be about $150). An optional entertainment add-on called *Piano Player* cost $15. It showed a <del>full-screen</del> man seated at a piano, playing it. His motions reacted to the music being played. !! See image in exidyboy's answer. I obviously remembered it wrong.

Comment: So it may have been a device from the same school of thought as the Covox Speech Thing — just an ADC connected to the parallel port which the CPU throws PCM data to?

Comment: @Tommy I have no idea now it worked. It was a case-less circuit board as wide as the DB25 connector it was physically attached to and maybe three inches long.  I believe Sorcerers had a full parallel port, not the "8 bits out / 4 bits in" thing which early PCs called a parallel port (but effective mostly for driving a dumb printer).  Howard Arrington probably made them at home.

Comment: Yes, it was a 'simple' DAC, two channel and 8 bit. All sound generation was done in software and **thus quite capable**, not restricted like sound chips of the same time. Number of voices is limited by whatever calculations the software could do in time. Much like modern sound generation. Except, where it's done today as a side job, almost for free, it occupied a great part of the Z80s capacity back then.

Comment: @Raffzahn Thank you. So pretty cool for 1980, right? ✨ My Sorcerer was the original 2 MHz model (later versions were 4 MHz). It's amazing to me that the "slow" processor could generate the polyphonic waveform.  And if *Piano Player* were running, it monitored the music and dynamically redefined character-mapped graphics to have him look like he was actually playing the given piece.

Comment: @RichF Well, considering that sound is comparable slow, it does leave room even back then to do the job. A 2 MHz Z80 can do more than 200k instructions per second. Audio does work already great with a 15-20 kHz resolution, so that's 10+ instructions per sample. Not much but can be done quite well, especially with some premade tables.

Comment: Here's a demo of a similar card also called "Music System". This one's for the S-100 bus, and it's a 1-bit filtered PWM, not 8-bit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FDigtF0dRQ#t=10m30s

Comment: Even without any extra hardware, a DAC can allow for some nice music.  On my Stella's Stocking cartridge menu for the Atari 2600, I generated four-voice music with a five-octave range at a 15,700Hz sample rate using 46 cycles out of every 76 (the remaining cycles were used to maintain the display).  The techniques I used would not have been workable on the Z80 (there's a joke about the 6502 having 128 16-bit address registers, but there's some real truth to it here, since within every group of four scan lines my code makes use of twenty different pointers held in zero page), but...

Comment: ...having an 8-bit DAC instead of 4-bit would allow use of a tone generation approach that's more suitable for the Z80.  When using a 4-bit DAC, quantizing noise will yield unwanted frequencies when playing pitches that are not power-of-two multiples of 15700/N, but using an 8-bit one would avoid that.  Four-voice waveform generation code with two output instructions would be 96+22=118 cycles without output or looping overhead, and six-voice code would be 140+22=162 cycles.  For pitch accuracy, the loop should be unrolled 16x, and loop overhead...

Comment: ...would probably be about 7-8 cycles/loop, yielding 126 cycles per sample for 4-void music, or 170 for 6-voice music.  So four-voice music at 15.7kHz or six-voice music at 11kHz would both seem possible, if one can tolerate some choppiness between notes.  Alternatively, it might be possible to play four-voice music at an 11kHz sample rate if one sets up a 5.5kHz timer-tick interrupt that outputs one sample at the start, calculates two samples, and outputs a sample at the end.

Comment: @supercat Thanks for the technical comments as well as your new answer.  While I'm a programmer, I was simply a satisfied user of the Music System.  For the most part, I typed in sheet music from hymn books and other sources and enjoyed learning about both musical notation and listening to the results.

Comment: @RichF: I forgot to mention in the comments that even if one were doing interrupt-driven music on the Z80, the main-line code would have to severely limit its register usage in order to keep interrupt overhead reasonable.  For four-voice music, an interrupt handler could reasonably easily leave BC, HL, AF, IX, and IY alone, while using AF', DE, BC', DE', and HL'.  Adding code to save/restore the latter registers would add an extra 105 cycles to the interrupt service time.   Spending 21 cycles to save/restore DE might be good, but it would cut down on the time available to the mainline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having looked into my best guess of where a competing product might be found in the same timeframe, the Apple II, the ever-questionable source of Wikipedia [offers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALF_Products#Apple_Music_Synthesizer_/_Music_Card_MC16):

> [The Music Card MC16] was the first hardware music product sold for
>   the Apple II ... demonstrated to Apple and Apple dealers late in 1978,
>   and volume sales began in June 1979.
>
> The sophisticated software written by John Ridges for this synthesizer
>   was the first to implement graphical entry for a personal computer
>   music product. [...] Since the Apple II had no mouse, the GUI was
>   implemented using the Apple's "game paddles"; one moved an arrow to
>   select the desired icon, and the other moved the selected icon to the
>   desired position on the musical staff on the screen display. When
>   entering a musical note, the sound of the note was simultaneously
>   played by the synthesizer for confirmation that the correct pitch had
>   been selected.
>
> ...
>
> Each card could produce three simultaneous voices, each with an 8 octave range (starting at the same pitch as a piano but extending 8 semitones higher) with excellent tuning accuracy (within 2 cents) and 256 envelope/volume levels with an exponential scaling (78 dB range). Each voice could also produce quarter tones (pitches exponentially halfway between each piano pitch). Two cards could be used for six voices or three cards for nine voices; with two or three cards the audio output was in stereo.

The related screenshot is:

[image]

The entire article also covers earlier S100 hardware from the same company that was more sonically capable, but unsurprisingly limited in terms of the user interface.

So to answer your question — "Did other systems of the era have these features?" — the Apple II had something similar a year earlier, but only three voices rather than four (unless you bought multiple cards).

I'd also distinguish this and the Exidy product from the game-oriented Pokey/SN/AY-type chips of the era as they seem to have put a lot of thought into pitch control rather than just thrown a variable clock divider at it and let the [non-linear] range fall where it may, so I didn't look seriously at the Atari 8-bit but I dare imagine that may have had some sort of composition software by 1980.

Comment: "was the first to implement graphical entry for a personal computer music product" - Atari's Music Composer was available when the machines were released and the copyright is 1979, so it might be close but no cigar either way.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Howard Arrington Piano Player aka Jukebox]

Recovered a few weeks ago from some Sorcerer floppies.

Comment: Wow, thank you!  I obviously remembered it wrong and thought the piano and its player were much larger.  Instead he's small, with most the screen showing the keyboard.  I'm still pretty sure he moved, though, with the added feature of the exact key(s) being played being indicated.

Comment: Yes his arms move and the grey squares flutter across the keyboard indicating which notes are being played.No photos or schematics exist of the actual Four Voice Music System hardware so if anyone reading this has the PCB please make yourself known or put up some hi-resolution photos somewhere.

Comment: What does "mockbird" refer too? A bird-like sound, or perhaps the Mockingboard?

Comment: MOCKBIRD is the name of the tune being played: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Listen_to_the_Mocking_Bird

Answer (score 3):

About your question which AD converter is used, you can ask Michael Borthwick at Swinburne University of Technology, Melbourne, VIC, Australia, a researcher.
He acquired and cloned the Arrington soundcard during his research work on the Australian and Dutch Exidy Sorcerer user groups.

Source: http://www.atariprotos.com/othersystems/sorcerer/hardware/arringtonmusic.htm

Comment: As can be seen from the hardware pictures at the link cited, the DAC is nothing but a resistor ladder (the article says 6 bits), similar to the COVOX/other homebrew digital sound solutions.

Answer (score 3):

If a computer has a decent DAC, it's possible to generate multi-voice music using CPU-based waveform generation.  I've done four-voice music on the Atari 2600, which has a pair of four-bit DACs.  There are a couple of approaches that can be taken for frequency generation, one of which is suitable for the 6502 and sound good even with lower-precision DACs, and one of which would need a higher-precision DAC but can be more efficiently accommodated on the Z80.

When using a low-precision DAC, unwanted sounds may occur at multiples of the waveform's "perfect repeat" rate.  If one were to try to output 3-bit, 1,471.8Hz waveform at a 15,700Hz sample rate, then three periods of that waveform would occur every 32 samples, meaning that tones would be produced at multiples of 490.6Hz.  The loudest would be the desired 1471.8Hz tone, but other unrelated tones would be produced as well, with an amplitude that could approach 1/7 of the desired signal (since on a 3-bit ADC each step would be 1/7 of full scale).

To avoid this, a 6502-based music player can ensure that every output pitch will be a power-of-two multiple or sub-multiple of 15700/N, where N ranges from 32 to 60.  This will yield pitches that are well in tune for some keys, and at least recognizable for all keys.  Such an approach would require using many different data pointers within the tone-generation loop, but since the 6502 can directly index off pointers stored in zero-page memory, this isn't a problem.

For the Z80, a different approach would be required, producing frequencies which are N/256L times the sample rate, where L is the number of times the tone-generation loop is unrolled.  This would likely yield unwanted quantizing noise artifacts if one were to try it with a 4-bit DAC, but such noise could be reduced by using a better DAC.  Computation time on the Z80 would be roughly proportional to the desired number of voices, up to six (using C, E, L, C', E', and L' as phase accumulators).

For machines which have an audio DAC available, the ability to play multi-voice music would be based largely on whether anyone had chosen to implement it.  Further, there wouldn't generally be a fixed upper limit on the number of voices, but instead the sound would become "fuzzier" as the number of voices was increased.